# Where I save the applet in tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, applet

I call an applet through a JSP...where I have to save it? and what the .class and the .java file? in which root in tomcat so when I call it from the JSP to be appeared?

here is the applet call from the jsp

```
%><%@ page language="java"%>
    <html>
    <body>
    <jsp:plugin code="g7appletDialog.class" codebase="" type="applet" width="300" height="200">
    <jsp:fallback>Unable to load applet</jsp:fallback>
    </jsp:plugin>
    <applet code=""g7appletDialog.class"" width="300" heigjt="200"></applet>
    </body>
    </html><%
```

Comment: I have tried almost everwhere in the tomcat localy to paste my applet (the .class and the .java file) and still didnt get any results from the call inside my JSP site when I m running the JSP...I dont know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The path to your servlet must be relative to your jsp. If you have a jsp in `web-inf/admin/pages/index.jsp`, then you can place the `.class` file in directory `web-inf/admin/pages/` and just have `code="g7appletDialog.class"`.

In case that you have a central repository for applets, lets say `web-inf/admin/applets` then you should change the code to `code="../applets/g7appletDialog.class"`.

The `../` gets you one dir back. To go two dirs back use `../../` and so on...

Comment: that means jsp site and .class have to be at the same root...or I have understand wrong....no its the first applet that I make for this project and all the JSP sites are in D:GET2\workspace\project\ so have to put the .class also here?

Comment: put it in the same dir as your jsp for starters to see if it works

Comment: Yeah I put and try it still deosnt work ...dont know why...java , .class and the jsp site all at the same dir and not working

Comment: do you want to upload also the applet ...its a simple applet that includes one JOptionPane.showConfrimDialog...for YES and NO...thats all